# Free memory created by instantiating base class with parent type that has protected destructor

Tags: c++, arduinojson

I think this is probably a really simple question, but I am as much a C++ developer as the guys at the walmart meat counter are butchers.

Say I have:

```
class Parent{
    protected:
        ~Parent(){};
};

class ChildA : public Parent{

};

struct Container{
    Parent *child;

    //Tried this, causes: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
    ~Container(){
        delete &child;
    }
};

Container MakeStruct(){
    ChildA child = *new ChildA();
    return Container { .child = &child };
}

int main()
{
    Container cont = MakeStruct();

    //Tried this, causes: "Parent::~Parent()" is inaccessible
    delete cont.child;
}
```

As you can see, I am using `new` to create a `ChildA` because I need it to outlive the `MakeStruct` function. So I know this means that `child` (in `MakeStruct`) will be placed on the heap, and that I am responsible for deleting it. But I can't seem to delete it.
I can't change the type of `child` in `Container` because I need it to accept both a `ChildA` and a `ChildB`. It sort of makes sense, considering the destructor of `Parent` is protected. I have no control over `Parent` or either `Child`. They are part of an external library.

I case it helps, the actual code I'm working with is a library called ArduinoJson.

I am trying to return either a `DynamicJsonDocument` or a `StaticJsonDocument<T>` from a function, wrapped in a struct taking a `JsonDocument`:

Here is the struct that contains the `JsonDocument`:

```
struct rpc_handler_result_t {
    esp_err_t result;
    JsonDocument *response;
};
```

which is returned from:

```
{
    const int len = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(1);
    StaticJsonDocument<len> reply = *new StaticJsonDocument<len>;

    reply["MaxOutput"] = Configuration::GetMaxOutputAmps();

    rpc_handler_result_t res = {
        .result = ESP_OK,
        .response = reply
    };

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you eventually call `delete`, you must pass it precisely the value you got from `new`. So you *must* store the value that `new` returns somewhere. But look at your call to `new` -- it dereferences that value and *never* stores it anywhere. So how can you call `delete`?!

```
 Container MakeStruct(){
    ChildA child = *new ChildA(); // The value returned by new is lost here
    return Container { .child = &child }; // child is a local object here
}
```

This is all wrong. You create a new object by calling `new`. But you do not store the value `new` returned anywhere. Now, `child` is a temporary object whose value was copy-constructed from the value of the object you allocated with `new` and leaked.

Then, you save the address of the temporary `child` object you created on the stack. But that object won't exist after you `return`.

What you wanted to do was save the *value* that `new` returned. But you got rid of it immediately by dereferencing it and never saving it.

So:

1. You *must* store the value that `new` returns so you can `delete` it later.
2. Don't try to pass addresses of local objects out of functions.

You wanted `.child = new ChildA()`, setting the `child` member to be a pointer to the object created by `new`, not a pointer to some temporary, local object. You can save the value `new` returns in a temporary if you want, just make sure `.child` gets the value `new` returned and not any other value.

Also:

```
Parent *child;

//Tried this, causes: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
~Container(){
    delete &child;
}
```

This is wrong too. What type is `&child`? Is `&child` something you got from `new`? This should be `delete child;`.

Comment: This is a great answer to a rookie mistake. Thanks for being so thorough. My only issue now is that when I change `delete &child` to `delete child` I get: `Parent::~Parent()"is inaccessible`. In this case, yes `child` is obtained from `new`. I thought that since `child`is a pointer to a `ChildA` or `ChildB` that in order to delete it I'd need to dereference it otherwise it's just try to delete the pointer. I really stand by my walmart meat counter comment...

Comment: @MatthewGoulart Why did you make `~Parent` inaccessible in `Container` if you want `Container` to be able to delete the `Parent` it has a pointer to? I'm confused about your objectives. Why is `~Parent` protected?

Comment: I don't have control over `Parent` unfortunately. It is `JsonDocument` at the bottom of my question, part of a library that I've imported. I thought about it and it makes sense that I can't `delete` the base class as the derived classes most likely have logic specific to their deletion in the overridden destructor.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart If the destructor isn't `virtual`, then you are correct that you can't delete the base class. That means your code for `Container` can't possibly work since it would have absolutely no way to know which destructor to invoke. Maybe use `std::unique_ptr` instead?

Comment: Funny you should mention `unique_ptr`. Before the current approach, I spend a good amount of time trying to get `unique_ptr` to work, but I think it might be broken on the esp32 (or I'm just as bad at that as I am this ;) ). Either way, you've helped me realize what I'm trying is probably too complicated and I should try (yet) another approach. Thanks.